# Debug my Google map Cluster Code

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, markerclusterer

I am using this code to create a Google map with 3 points that are hidden within one and when the one marker is clicked thepoints either get merged into the one or they open up into 3 separate ones, however the map is not appearing can any one examine my code and see the potential problem?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>favorite cities</title>
    <style>
      html, body, #map-canvas {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px
      }
    </style>
   <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp"></script>
    <script>
      (function() {
        window.onload = function(){
          var options = {
            zoom: 3,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.99, -93.77),
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
          };
          var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), options);
          
          var mgr = new MarkerManager(map);
          var A = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(37.99, -93.77),
            icon: 'img/cluster.png'
          });
          google.maps.event.addListener(A, 'click', function() {
            map.setZoom(7);
            map.setCenter(Kloof.getPosition());
          });
          
          var Cities = [A];
          var Schools = [
            //SChool1
       new google.maps.Marker({position: new google.maps.LatLng(38.99, -93.97)}),
                                    //School2
       new google.maps.Marker({position: new google.maps.LatLng(37.89, -94.77)}),
                                    //School3
       new google.maps.Marker({position: new google.maps.LatLng(37.79, -95.77)})
                                    ];
                                    google.maps.event.addListener(mgr, 'loaded', function() {
                                    agr.addMarkers(Cities, 11, 6);
                                    agr.addMarkers(Schools, 6);
                                    agr.refresh
                                   });
                                   };
                                   })();
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Missing arguments in and comma after `position: new google.maps.LatLng()`. `Area` is invalid Array. Fix syntax errors and argument issues and get back to us.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  If your "real" data is "restricted" provide test data that allows the issue to be reproduced.

Comment: @PHPglue still no map is appearing

Comment: @geocodezip thank you for the tip it is updated with sample data now

Comment: I get `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier` on your code snippet (just like PHPglue...), fixing that (as suggested) gives more syntax errors `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ;` on this line `var Cities = [A;`

Comment: @geocodezip i repaired that now but still no map

Comment: You need to learn to use the javascript console.  Now I get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetWidth' of null`, because there is no element with id='map' on your page. Then `Uncaught ReferenceError: MarkerManager is not defined` (but a map)

Comment: @geocodezip there is a '<div id="map-canvas"></div>'

Comment: @geocodezip so what do I do to fix that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the code to the following:

```js
<
    var schoolArray = []; //Global array to store the POINTS
    var SchoolPoints = [[-29.788911, 30.852721, 'Thomas More College'], //I am creating a global array to store the MARKERS
                [-29.781297, 30.838465, 'Kloof Senior Primary School'],
                [-29.827008, 30.881706, 'Pinetown Boys HighSchool']];  

    function initialize() { //I am initializing the google map and how it will appear on my dashboard
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 9,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(-29.807762, 30.854261),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

  var mcOptions = { //this is where i determine BY GRID the amount of tiles that will determine if my schools points cluster or if they are separate and also the max zoom level the individual points are visual at 
        gridSize: 25,
        maxZoom: 20
    };
  var mc = new MarkerClusterer(map, [], mcOptions); //this creates the blue cluster you see initially on the map

  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function() { //upon click the map zooms in and displays the 3 schools with separate markers
        infowindow.close();
    });

    // This is where the markers are added to the map and sorted into the cluster
  for(var i=0; i<SchoolPoints.length; i++){ //This is where where i am setting up my markers on the map based off the number of elements within the points array
         createMarker(new google.maps.LatLng(SchoolPoints[i][0], SchoolPoints[i][1]), SchoolPoints[i][2]);
    }
    
  mc.addMarkers(schoolArray , true); //now the markers are clustered together in the blue symbol
}

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({ //I am determining the size of the info window that will be displayed by my school points
    size: new google.maps.Size(500, 250)
});

  function createMarker(latlng, html) { //this function is where i create the individual markers
    var contentString = html;
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latlng,
        map: map,
        icon: '',       
    });

  marker.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.DROP); //I decided for aesthetic reasons i would like to see if i could animate the markers and so i added a drop animation
    
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() { //when clicking the markers their info windows are displayed
    infowindow.setContent(contentString); //This sets the info window to have the content listed in the array visible
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
    });
    
    schoolArray.push(marker); 
}

window.onload = initialize;
 
​
```

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), options);
```

To:

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), options);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>favorite cities</title>
    <style>
      html, body, #map-canvas {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px
      }
    </style>
   <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp"></script>
    <script>
      (function() {
        window.onload = function(){
          var options = {
            zoom: 3,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.99, -93.77),
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
          };
          var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), options);
          
          var mgr = new MarkerManager(map);
          var A = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(37.99, -93.77),
            icon: 'img/cluster.png'
          });
          google.maps.event.addListener(A, 'click', function() {
            map.setZoom(7);
            map.setCenter(Kloof.getPosition());
          });
          
          var Cities = [A];
          var Schools = [
            //SChool1
       new google.maps.Marker({position: new google.maps.LatLng(38.99, -93.97)}),
                                    //School2
       new google.maps.Marker({position: new google.maps.LatLng(37.89, -94.77)}),
                                    //School3
       new google.maps.Marker({position: new google.maps.LatLng(37.79, -95.77)})
                                    ];
                                    google.maps.event.addListener(mgr, 'loaded', function() {
                                    agr.addMarkers(Cities, 11, 6);
                                    agr.addMarkers(Schools, 6);
                                    agr.refresh
                                   });
                                   };
                                   })();
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The map is now loading thank you for that, however my points are not appearing, well at least not on my screen... do you know what could be wrong?

Comment: From my earlier comment - Then `Uncaught ReferenceError: MarkerManager is not defined` (but a map)